# WCF restriction for the amount of simultaneously proceeding threads from one client

Tags: wcf, web-services, silverlight, asmx, silverlight-5.0

I ve created wcf-service in  asp.net application, that hosts silverlight application as well, that has only one method:

```
public void TestMethod(int idRequest)
    {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(idRequest);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
    }
```

I activate this method asynchronously from silverlight app by pushing on the button:

```
 private static int countRequest = 0;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                countRequest++;

                WCFServiceManager.WCFServiceClient serviceRef = new WCFServiceManager.WCFServiceClient();
                serviceRef.TestMethodAsync(countRequest);
    }
```

it's possible to activate the method only 6 times (I look at  VS, window Output), the other inquiries are at the row and while one from 6 threads won't finish its execution, a new one won't start in TestMethod. More than 6 inquiries are sending from the client (it's displayed in httpFox). What is connected with the restriction? How can we increase the amount from 6 to 50 for example? Thank you in advance. I appreciate your help.

WS 2010, Window Output:
imageshack.us/a/img580/1416/outputqn.png

HttpFox:
imageshack.us/a/img546/6461/httpfox.png

[Project, vs2010, silverlight 5.0](http://zalil.ru/34239236)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is about Silverlight security limitations which is related to prevent DOS attacks. In addition to this, it is also related with browsers configuration. Each browser has different connection limitation such as 6, 8, 12 calls. You can test this but do not use 1 hour sleep. :) 10 seconds will be enought to detect. Also follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259466/silverlight-concurrent-wcf?rq=1) for more information.